# Using IF Statements And Toggle to Clean Up TradingView Indicator?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a toggle at the top of my indicator where I determine if I'm using a Light or Dark Color Theme:

```
toggleDarkColors = input.bool(true, title = "Toggle Dark Colors", group=g2)
toggleLightColors = input.bool(false, title = "Toggle Light Colors", group=g2)
```

Colors:

```
londonTradingWDColor = color.new(#66d9ef, 99) //  Dark
londonTradingWLColor = color.new(#66d9ef, 93) //  Light
```

I use the colors above to display my trading window on my chart:

```
LondonTW = input(title='London Trading Window', defval=true, group=g6)
londonTradingWindow = toggleTradingWindow and is_session(londonTradingW)
bgcolor(toggleDarkColors and londonTradingWindow and LondonTW ? londonTradingWDColor : na)
bgcolor(toggleLightColors and londonTradingWindow and LondonTW ? londonTradingWLColor : na)
```

The 2 issues I'm having is when I click on the "Style" menu in the indicator settings:

[image]

**#01**

I have 2 checkboxes with "Background Color" displaying because I have 2 bgcolor()'s above.
Is there any way to dislay only 1 instead of 2 depending on which Color theme is toggled? I tried if statements:

```
LondonTW = input(title='London Trading Window', defval=true, group=g6)
londonTradingWindow = toggleTradingWindow and is_session(londonTradingW)

LOTWDark = bgcolor(londonTradingWindow and LondonTW ? londonTradingWDColor : na)
LOTWLight = bgcolor(londonTradingWindow and LondonTW ? londonTradingWLColor : na)

if toggleDarkColors
    LOTWDark
    
if toggleLightColors    
    LOTWLight
```

I got the error: `line 551: Void expression cannot be assigned to a variable`
Line 551 is `LOKZDark = bgcolor(londonOKillZone and LondonOKZ ? londonOpenKZDColor : na)`

**#02**

How do I alter the `bgcolor()` above code to give it a title? I checked `bgcolor()` on tradingviews pinescript v5 page and I couldn't figure it out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**#1**

No it is not possible. But why don't you use one input for that? Say you only keep `toggleDarkColors` and if it is `true` then it is dark color. If it is `false`, then it is light color.

**#2**
`bgcolor()` has a `title` argument.

> bgcolor(color, offset, editable, show_last, title) → void

> title (const string) Title of the bgcolor. Optional argument.

## Edit

Use one input for the color option. If `true`, use dark color, if `false` use light color. One variable for the color is enough. Then use this variable in `bgcolor()`.

```
toggleDarkColors = input.bool(true, title = "Toggle Dark Colors", group=g2)
londonTradingColor = toggleDarkColors ? color.new(#66d9ef, 99) : color.new(#66d9ef, 93)
bgcolor(londonTradingWindow and LondonTW ? londonTradingColor : na)
```